# android app crashed on loading new intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i am making an android app were you can practice multiplication. you select an number from 1 trough 10 and then you get 10 questions. after those then you get redirected back to the menu. but after that if you do another set of 10 questions the app crashes after the last question.

```
package com.example.rick2.rekentuin_native;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OefenenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int index = 0;
int intArray[] = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
TextView tv2;
String sessionId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_oefenen);

    sessionId = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
    TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    tv1.setText(sessionId);



    tv2 = findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    tv2.setText(Integer.toString(intArray[index]));
}

public void CheckAns(View view) {
    EditText edit = findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    Integer result = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());
    int number1 = Integer.parseInt(sessionId);

    if (result == intArray[index] * number1) {
        if (index < 10) {
            index++;
            tv2.setText(Integer.toString(intArray[index]));
            edit.setText("");
        }
        else{
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MenuOefenActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    }
    else{
        edit.setText("");
    }
}

}
```

logcat does give me this error but i cant find any onclick that doesnt work.

```
2019-03-23 13:49:44.066 24510-24510/com.example.rick2.rekentuin_native E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rick2.rekentuin_native, PID: 24510
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10
    at com.example.rick2.rekentuin_native.OefenenActivity.CheckAns(OefenenActivity.java:40)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in line #40 of your activity: `tv2.setText(Integer.toString(intArray[index]));`

The reason is that you increment index of element to extract **before** getting requesting array. So, you have two options:

a) initialize the `index` field with `-1`

OR

b) reorder lines:

```
  tv2.setText(Integer.toString(intArray[index]));
  index++;
```

instead of

```
  index++;
  tv2.setText(Integer.toString(intArray[index]));
```

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MenuOefenActivity.class);
```

try this one:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(OefenenActivity.this, MenuOefenActivity.class);
```

i hope it can help :-)